# UIImageView, when in a XIB, uses which UIImage method?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, interface-builder

As far as I can tell, `UIImageView`s in XIBs don't use `+imageNamed`.  I also tried `+imageWithContentsOfFile`, but that was no dice also.

**Which UIImage method do Interface Builder XIBs use to load images in `ImageView`s?**

Comment: I'm also wondering this. I was just trying to swizzle the imageNamed function so that it would automatically load ~568h images, but that didn't work from images defined in the XIB file.

Comment: It's `initWithCoder:` and it's very annoying to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

See the link given below, it will might help you. Most probably 3rd Answer will help you,

[How can I change the image displayed in an UIImageView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706240/how-can-i-change-the-image-displayed-in-an-uiimageview-programmatically)

the last method shoud be fired when you set image in XIB

```
    [YOURCONTROLLER.imageToDisplay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:value]];
```