# How can I display a UIImage in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, storyboard

I am playing around with Xcode 5 and storyboarding. I'm at the point where I have captured a `UIImage` using the camera, but I can't figure out how to display the image on the phone after I've captured it. I have specified an `IBOutlet UIImageView` and set it's value to the image that I captured from the camera, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

This is my interface:

```
@interface HCViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

And this is my `didFinishPickingWithMediaInfo` method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Get the picture from the camera
    UIImage *imageFromCamera = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // Set the IBOutlet UIImageView to the picture from the camera
    // This does nothing as far as I can tell
    self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFromCamera];

    // Let's take a closer look at this
    NSLog(@"%@", self.image);

    // Close the camera view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is what I see in the logger for `self.image`:

```
2013-09-10 17:17:45.169 YourMom[6136:60b] <UIImageView: 0x1556fdc0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x155d5b10>>
```

My storyboard has a View Controller with two different scenes that can be swiped back and forth. Both of the scenes have a "View" with an "Image View" as a sub-item. The Image Views each have "Referencing Outlets" that seem to be connected to the `image` variable that I defined in my interface. However, simply setting the value of `image` doesn't change the phone display.

After reading this SO question: [How can I change the image displayed in an UIImageView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706240/how-can-i-change-the-image-displayed-in-an-uiimageview-programmatically) I tried `[self.image setImage:image]`, but that didn't appear to do anything either. How do I tell Xcode that I want `image` to show up in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in this:

```
self.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFromCamera];
```

Because you are using Storyboard your `UIImageView` will be initialized for you. By executing this line of code you are throwing away an old `UIImageView` and replacing it with a new `UIImageView` that has no frame.

You just need to do this:

```
[self.image setImage:imageFromCamera]
```

Also, you might be getting the wrong image from info. Try `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`.
Hope this is helpful, cheers!

Comment: You were right on both counts. Thanks very much. I love StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

```
// this is your delegate method to set the image taken from your camera

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 // Get the picture from the camera
    UIImage *imageFromCamera = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

 // alloc image view as you have to set it image on it
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgView.image = imageFromCamera;

// you can also set the image on button like this 
    UIImage *imageFromCamera = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
// imgBtn is UIButton property
    [self.imgBtn setImage:imageFromCamera forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Let's take a closer look at this
    NSLog(@"%@", self.image);

// Close the camera view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIImage View has an property called `image`.

This property is of type `UIImage`.

So if you have an `UIImage`, then you can set the property as follows:

```
imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to display your image.

```
imageView.image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
```

Hope this can help you with your problems.