# Different images for different dimensions on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, dimension

I am making an application which I would like to use the same image for multiple dimensions without stretching or cropping the image.

Can I make different images each supporting a dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent stretching, you would have to create a different image for all supported iOS dimensions. Then, using your code, choose the correct image source according to the device's dimension.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635483/how-to-get-screen-size-using-code) about getting the device dimensions.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706240/how-can-i-change-the-image-displayed-in-an-uiimageview-programmatically) about changing the image source.

Comment: Thanks a lot! sorry but i do not have enough reputation to like.

Comment: It's OK :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contentMode` as `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` of UIImageView's Property.

It will be fit to your imageView, and will not be stretching or cropping.
It will mainain aspect ratio of image.
i.e

```
imgDevider.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: **Thanks so much!** and again  sorry i do not have enough reputation to like.